# Why a Container widget with an image wrapped in Expanded widget gets smaller as I add more widgets to Column?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

As I add widgets to a Column widget Container wrapped in Expanded widget gets smaller. Even if I try to increase the height of the container(or the image) it does not change.

How can I solve the problem?

Here is the image
[image]

Here is the widget function

```
Widget _buildWomanProductContainer({
required double width,
required double height,
required String imagePath,
required String clothProductName,
required String clothType,
required String clothPrice,}) {
return Column(children: [
  Expanded(
    child: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: height,
      width: width,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
        child: Image.asset(
          imagePath,
          height: height,
          width: width,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
          colorBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  const SizedBox(height: 8),
  Text(clothProductName,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 67, 59, 1),
        fontFamily: 'Merriweather-Regular',
      )),
  Text(clothType,
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 67, 59, 0.5),
          fontFamily: 'Merriweather-Regular',
          fontSize: 12)),
  OutlinedButton(child: Text("Button"), onPressed: () {})
]);}
```

Comment: But then the image is of fixed size

Comment: Set size to the image. Wrap your column with Expanded.

Comment: It does not work

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem eventually!

1. We replace the root Column widget with a Wrap widget
2. We set the alignment: WrapAlignment.center because initially Wrap widget sets our position to the left
3. Other widgets that are not the image.asset(wrapped inside of a container) we wrap inside of a column.

As a result we do not have overflow issues or limitations in manipulating geometry of an image

Providing the updated code:

```
Widget _buildWomanProductContainer({
required double width,
required double height,
required String imagePath,
required String clothProductName,
required String clothType,
required String clothPrice,}) {
return Wrap(
  alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
      children: [
    Container(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: Image.asset(
        imagePath,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
        colorBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
      ),
    ),

    Column(children: [
      const SizedBox(height: 8),
    Text(clothProductName,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 67, 59, 1),
          fontFamily: 'Merriweather-Regular',
        )),
    Text(clothType,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 67, 59, 0.5),
            fontFamily: 'Merriweather-Regular',
            fontSize: 12)),
    OutlinedButton(
      child: Text(clothPrice,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 67, 59, 1),
              fontFamily: 'SolomonSans-SemiBold')),
      onPressed: () {},
      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        side: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 67, 59, 1)),
      ),
    )
    ],)
    
  ],
);
```

}